# Button removes list items and changes their ordning | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that is supposed to toggle more items in a list when pressing it. I set the default state in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    showCount: 10,
    expanded: false
  }
}
```

So the default number of items in the list will be 10 and it's not expanded. Then I created a function that is supposed to change the state and load more list items:

```
loadMore() {
  const { showCount } = this.state
  const { events } = this.props
  showCount === 10
    ? this.setState({ showCount: events.reverse().length, expanded: true })
    : this.setState({ showCount: 10, expanded: false })
}
```

And created a "button" that is supposed to change it's text if the `expanded` state is true or false:

```
const toggleMore = (
  <div className="text-center">
    <a className="show-more" onClick={() => this.loadMore()}>
      {this.state.expanded ? (
        <span>Visa mindre</span>
      ) : (
        <span>Visa mer</span>
      )}
    </a>
  </div>
)
```

And then the list item component that uses `.slice` with the `showCount` variable:

```
const mappedEvents =
  events.length === 0 ? (
    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>No events</p>
  ) : (
    events
      .reverse()
      .slice(0, this.state.showCount)
      .map((event, i) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <EventItem
              key={i}
              ...
            />
          </div>
        )
      })
  )
```

#### My Problems

So this button works great the first time I use it. If I come to my page I can see all of the 10 list items and when pressing the button the text changes. **But** when I press it a second time (when the `expanded: true`) all of my list items **disappears**. And when I press it the third time the order of my list items changes, meaning that `.revers()` apparently doesn't work anymore. And when I press it the fourth time it goes back to the first stage; 10 list items and the ordning is as it should be. And after that it just keeps repeating.

So I just want to know what I am doing wrong here and why the button acts like this.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try `onClick={this.loadMore.bind(this)}`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for replying. Tried it with no luck :(

Comment: Hi, a couple of questions:
1) could you, pls, explain, why are you using reverse? I can't grasp it from looking at the provided code.
2) Where do you define the toggleMore and mappedEvents consts?

Comment: I built this https://codesandbox.io/s/zxmjkr4l3x Seems to work ok.

Comment: @GlebKost Yes, I am using reverse() because of I need to get the newest list item from my API. And I define those two consts inside of my render().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that events.reverse() is destructive, it actually *mutates* the original array, it doesn't simply return a new reversed array. This array is coming from props which is also a problem -- you definitely shouldn't modify something that is coming from props, you don't know if the parent component will later overwrite it with a new array.

Also if you are using reverse() during render, remember render probably runs a whole bunch more times that you might realise. Each time it renders it will reverse the array yet again.

What I would suggest here is only perform the array transform during render, and do things in a non-destructive way. One way to get a new reversed array is to first make a copy with slice and *then* reverse it, as follows:

```
const reversed = events.slice().reverse();
```

Also I note you are using `events.reverse().length` -- presumably this is the same as events.length, do you need to mutate the array here?

Comment: Something I noticed is that when I remove `reverse()` at `events.reverse().length` it doesn't remove the list items the third time I press the button, but when pressing the button to expand everything the list is no longer reversed, until I press it again.

Comment: I explained this, every time you render you are reversing the array yet again.
I can't really debug this any more without seeing the complete component code, I'm not sure how these snippets interact with each other.

Comment: I understand. I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/Martinnord/2ccf20edf72af2c4ffb23d4ea9846192
Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: Looking at this I am still not entirely sure why the list *disappears*.

Comment: But .reverse() is a massive problem. Do you understand the statement "Array.reverse() is a destructive operation"?

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm just uncertain how I should reverse the array when I want it to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the reversing part, I'm not fully sure you need it in the end. And pull out those consts into separate methods or even separate small components.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List events={[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]} />
    );
  }
}

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showCount: 10,
      expanded: false
    }
    this.renderMappedEvents = this.renderMappedEvents.bind(this);
    this.renderToggleMoreBtn = this.renderToggleMoreBtn.bind(this);
  }

  loadMore() {
    const { showCount } = this.state
    const { events } = this.props
    showCount === 10
      ? this.setState({ showCount: events.length, expanded: true })
      : this.setState({ showCount: 10, expanded: false })
  }

  renderMappedEvents() {
    const { events } = this.props; 
    return events.length === 0 ? (
    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>No events</p>
    ) : (
      events
        .slice(0, this.state.showCount)
        .map((event, i) => {
          return (
            <div>
              { event }
            </div>
          )
        })
    )
  }

  renderToggleMoreBtn() {
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
        <a className="show-more" onClick={() => this.loadMore()}>
          {this.state.expanded ? (
            <span>Visa mindre</span>
          ) : (
            <span>Visa mer</span>
          )}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{[
        this.renderMappedEvents(),
        this.renderToggleMoreBtn()
      ]}</div>);
  }

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And a link to the working snippet: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kmdz9f

Comment: BTW, if you could provide your not working solution as a working snippet, I'd be able to point out exactly where it gets broken.

Comment: Ok, now i think i get the reversing requirement, because you need the latest events from the array that you get from somewhere.

I'd second @Peter Hurst and do the ```events.slice().reverse();``` preferably once somewhere and not on every render.